# Argo CD image updater is not updating multiple images defined in the manifest file

Tags: argocd

Here is my ArgoCD manifest file.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: dev-k3s
  namespace: argocd
  annotations:
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: app1_img=git.test.com:4567/app1:latest, app2_img=git.test.com:4567/app2:latest
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app1_img.update-strategy: digest
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app2_img.update-strategy: digest
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: <repo_url>
    path: dev-k3s
    targetRevision: HEAD
  destination:
    server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
    namespace: dev-namespace
  syncPolicy:
    automated: {}
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
      - ApplyOutOfSyncOnly=true
```

Currently **app2** gets updated on every new image being pushed to docker registry. **app1** doesn't get updated.

when I described the pod, I could see **app2** docker image is tagged with sha256 and **app1** image is tagged with latest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation of ArgoCD and the Image Updater plugin.  It seems ArgoCD/ImageUpdater will fail to trigger a sync under the following (at least) conditions:

1. Application annotated with multiple images
2. The registry URLS contain a `:`, for example

```html
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: app1_img=git.test.com:4567/app1:latest, app2_img=git.test.com:4567/app2:latest
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app1_img.update-strategy: digest
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app2_img.update-strategy: digest
```

ArgoCD is having trouble parsing the image-list when there are multiple images and registy URLs have a port.

For some reason the last image in image-list gets sync’d and updated but the first does not.
See https://github.com/argoproj-labs/argocd-image-updater/issues/516  under Additional Context.

So, moving the image registry to port 443 (For example, registry.test.com) while maintaining backwards compatibility where registry.test.com targets or re-directs traffic to the image registry at git.test.com:4567

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kustomization you sould use `argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/<image_alias>.kustomize.image-name:` annotation

https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration/images/#custom-images-with-kustomize

in your application

```
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: app1_img=git.test.com:4567/app1:latest, app2_img=git.test.com:4567/app2:latest
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app1_img.update-strategy: digest
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app2_img.update-strategy: digest
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app1_img.kustomize.image-name: git.test.com:4567/app1:latest
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/app2_img.kustomize.image-name: git.test.com:4567/app2:latest
```

Please delete .argocd-source yaml file from your git repository if you are using `write-back-method: git`